# What kinds of variables range over proofs?

Tags: logic, terminology, constructive-mathematics, type-theory, intuitionistic-logic

I hope this question does not seem to obscure...

Consider the standard inference rule schema for, say, conjunction:

```
Rule (ConjunctionIntroduction)
  Premises
    P
    Q
  Conclusion
    P∧Q
```

If we are working intuitionistically, this is really a shorthand for the following (as far as my understanding goes):

```
Rule (ConjunctionIntroduction)
  Premises
    ρ ⊢ p::P
    σ ⊢ q::Q
  Conclusion
    ρ,σ ⊢ r::P∧Q
```

That is, rather than just stating that `P` holds, we state that there is a context `ρ` in which the proof `p` is a proof of `P`. And so on for the other premise and the conclusion.

Now `P` and `Q` are (what I would call) "metavariables" or "propositional variables". And `ρ` and `σ` are what I would call "context variables". So if I had to explicitly instruct a verifier, rather than hope that it could work out the various kinds of variables at play, I would prepend the following declarations:

```
Metavariables P,Q
Contexts ρ,σ
```

But what about the variables which range over proofs? Up until now I've also considered them metavariables, but this is clearly wrong. Consider the following:

```
Type NaturalNumber
...
Variable n:NaturalNumber
```

On the left of the type assertion we have a (normal, say) variable, the value of which would be a term or an expression. And on the right there is a type. But if I wanted to consider such assertions more generally, I would have to invent type variables to range over types:

```
Variable x
TypeVariable T
...
x:T
```

Clearly type variables and (normal) variables aren't the same at all.

Up until now I haven't considered the kinds of variables needed to range over proofs. In fact it's worse, I've been conflating them with metavariables. However, the example of variables versus type variables shows me I've been wrong. Googling around, however, I don't see the notion proof variables anywhere. So what should I call them? Or are others also conflating these two kinds of variables? Or have a got something else completely wrong?

I'm tempted to just do this...

```
Metavariables P,Q
Contexts ρ,σ
Proofs p,q,r
```

...and leave it at that. Should I?

By the way, I know I should strictly write `ContextVariables` for `Contexts` and `ProofVariables` for `Proofs` but I think the intention is clear.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: By the way, I don't think there's anything specifically _intuitionistic_ about wanting the contexts (and possibly proof terms) to be manifest in one's judgements and rules. It is a style that is more prevalent in fields and traditions that (for mostly independent reasons) are more likely to consider intuitionistic logic than general logic textbooks tend to do, but that is correlation, not causation. You can perfectly well define intuitionistic logic in Hilbert style without environments, or conversely include environments in classical natural deduction.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is not common in the *mathematical logic* tradition to have variables that range over proofs.

The kind of rules you envisage are most commonly encountered in the context of the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), where the objects that encode proof structure are *terms of the lambda calculus*. Accordingly, metavariables that range over these could be called *term variables*. It is common to use the letters $M, N,$ etc. for these variables.

For your "context" variables $\rho$ and $\sigma$, one most often sees *upper-case* Greek letters, starting with $\Gamma, \Delta, \ldots$.

So in fully decorated form, your conjunction introduction rule could look like
$$ \frac{\Gamma\vdash M:P \qquad\qquad \Delta\vdash N:Q}{\Gamma, \Delta \vdash \langle M,N\rangle : P \land Q } $$

(Beware that there are many minor stylistic variations possible here. The choices in the above example may have a slight computer-science bias, since that's where I'm coming from, but mathematical logicians should still find it reasonably familiar).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, firstly. At first glance you seem to have fallen into the same trap as I did in that you refer to the 'metavariables that range over $M$, $N$...' (forgive the paraphrasing). But with a closer inspection, I think what you have done is good, in that you refer to variables on both sides of the assertions as metavariables.

Comment: So for $x:T$ we have variables on both sides, namely term (or what I've called normal) variables on the left and type variables on the right. Wheres for, say $\rho \langle p::P$ we have three different kinds of *metavariables*, namely context, term (or proof) and type (or propositional). I like this distinction!

Comment: The only trouble of course is that many conflate metavariables and propositional variables. But I think to use the word 'metavariable' as container the aforementioned three kinds of variables is a very good idea.

Comment: @JamesSmith: I debated whether to add a paragraph warning about $P$ and $Q$ as metavariables, because some readers would assume they are propositional variables. Personally I prefer using $A, B, C$ as propositional variables and $\varphi, \psi$ etc as metavariables ranging over formulae; that's more unambiguous.

Comment: I think for my edification and the reader's you should make your own understanding of the difference between metavariables and propositional variables very clear. Am I along the right lines in my previous comments?

Comment: Apologies, the previous assertion should (of course) have been $\rho\vdash p::P$. I ran out of time when correcting it.

Comment: @JamesSmith: I didn't see anything in your comments that conflicted with my view, so I assumed we were on the same page. Propositional variables are found _inside_ concrete formulae, and in the (classical) semantics of the propositional calculus we have a map from propositional variables to _truth values_. Metavariables are used for _speaking about_ formulae at the metalevel (such as when defining a rule); each of those is understood to be instantiated to a concrete _formula_ at some point before get get a formula that has meaning _in_ the system.

Comment: Okay, I think I have what I need, thank you. By the way the BNF that formalises this particular vernacular can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/occam-proof-assistant/Parsers/master/es6/florence/bnf.js). Based on what I've learned this evening, I clearly have some adjustments to make.

Comment: I'd probably say "term metavariables" if I didn't just say "terms" and assume it to be understood that $M$ and $N$ are metavariables for those terms. "Term variable" comes a bit too close to "variable terms" (or just "variables") like the $x$ in $\lambda x.x$.

Comment: @JamesSmith Another way of thinking about it is that a metavariable, in general, stands for some piece of syntax. That means each syntactic class has its own notion of "metavariable". You have metavariables for terms/proofs, metavariables for types/formulas, metavariables for contexts. You can have metavariables for whole derivations, and if you had, say, a pattern matching syntax, you could have metavariables for patterns. A (plain) variable is usually an explicit concept within the syntax.

Comment: @DerekElkins: And, most confusing of all, metavariables for variable symbols.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Indeed.

Comment: @DerekElkins, I think we're on the same page exactly. It seems to me that any formal language for a verifier actually consists of two distinct (but inexorably bound) languages, namely a language (to overload that usage) and a metalanguage. Formally, then, variables appear in the language, and metavariables appear in the metalanguage.

Comment: Therefore in fact the only variables are term variables, the values of which are terms and expressions. Metavariables include type variables, proof (term) variables, context variables and statement variables. From now on I'm going to avoid the phrase 'propositional variable' because although @HenningMakholm draws a distinction between propositional variables and metvariables, the distinction elsewhere can vary and too often the two are conflated.

Answer (score 2):

Let me go full formal on you.

Consider these data type declarations of the syntax for the typed lambda calculus in [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php).

```
data TType : Set where
    TTVar : Nat -> TType                    -- α
    _=>_ : TType -> TType -> TType          -- τ → τ
    Forall : TType -> TType                 -- ∀α. τ

mutual
    data TExpr : Set where
        TVal : TValue -> TExpr              -- v
        TApp : TExpr -> TExpr -> TExpr      -- f x
        TTyApp : TExpr -> TType -> TExpr    -- e[τ]
        TVar : Nat -> TExpr                 -- x

    data TValue : Set where
        TLambda : TType -> TExpr -> TValue  -- λx:τ.e
        TTyLambda : TExpr -> TValue         -- Λτ.e
        TConst : Nat -> TValue              -- c
```

In this case, Agda itself is a the metalanguage. A type variable would be a value of the form `TTVar n` for some natural number `n`<sup>1</sup>. A term variable would be a value of the form `TVar n` for some natural number `n`.

A type metavariable is a variable *of Agda* of type `TType`. An expression metavariable is a variable of Agda of type `TExpr`. Finally, a value metavariable is a variable of Agda of type `TValue`. (Also, there are natural number metavariables.)

Of course, for a different object language there would be different data types describing the syntax, but a metavariable is always the same thing in this context: a variable of Agda of some given type. That is, a variable of the metalanguage. Other notions of "variable", if any, will depend on the object language.

As to your final question of whether you should write `ContextVariables` or `Contexts`, etc., it's up to you. I would probably lean toward just `Contexts` etc. I consider a variable of Agda (i.e. a metavariable) of type `TExpr` to "be" an expression (i.e. value of type `TExpr`) just as much as a concrete value. If I was talking *about* a function in the Agda code, I would not say "this function takes an expression metavariable" but that it "takes an expression". Even when informally writing about e.g. the typed lambda calculus, I would say "given terms $M$ and $N$, $\langle M,N\rangle$ is a term". The only case where I think I would prefer something like `ContextVariables` is if `Contexts` introduced constants of the metalanguage, and it was also necessary to explicitly state which symbols were variables (of the metalanguage) or not.

<sup>1</sup> And now the discussion potentially involves meta-metavariables...

Comment: Similarly, in Coq, you could look at https://github.com/dschepler/coq-sequent-calculus/blob/master/ClassicalND.v (disclaimer: I wrote that) which formalizes a version of classical natural deduction for propositional logic.  There, `prop atom` is propositions, `list (prop atom)` is what I used for contexts, and `classical_ND_proves Gamma P` is the (dependent) type of proofs of `P` in the context `Gamma`.  (Also, I used mostly invariant contexts, instead of the more "linear logic" type of context combination that the OP seems to be using.)

Comment: This is fantastic. Funnily enough I also thought of the definition of the untyped lambda calculus this morning as a good exercise.

Comment: @DerekElkins, ah yes, I was hoping to avoid meta-metavariables...

Comment: @DerekElkins, in the Florence vernacular (my flowery synonym for 'language' that I was thinking of dropping), I was thinking of allowing the user to only distinguish between variables and metavariables, but internally making the distinction in the grammar between the various kinds of each (although there is only one kind of variable as far as I can tell although (again) you hint that there might be others).

Comment: @DanielSchepler, thanks for the reference. I took a look. I see what I suspect are examples of Coq support for custom grammars there, in particular the use of levels. I am just finding out myself there are can be problems with precedence, see for example...

https://openmathematics.org/#negatives